# Test two samples with correlated observations within sample

Tags: repeated-measures, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, two-sample

I have repeated observations from individuals that have been randomly assigned to either Group 1 or Group 2. In detail, 64 subjects were randomly assigned to one of the two groups and performed a task 30 times. The experiment was designed such that each period should be viewed as an independent decision.
My question is: can I use a non-parametric test such as Mann–Whitney U test or K-S test to see if the two groups are different? Or the fact that I have repeated measures from the same person (even though by design each observation should be viewd as independent) violates tests assumptions such as iid?

I did try to take the average for each person and then run a non-parametric test using individual averages but I do not have enough power.

Edit: In the experiment I used techniques that are standard to experimental economics. Basically I have participants performing an interactive task with an opponent for 30 rounds. They are paid conditional on their performance, not a fixed fee. Each round participants are randomly re-matched, i.e., they are assigned to a different opponents. Everything is anonymous, so no reputation effect. Moreover, rounds are incentivised such that they are viewd as independent from each other (one random round is selected for payment at the end of the experiment). Participants know that from the very beginning.

Comment: Can you tell us why you think that the repeated measurements from one same person are independent?

Comment: In the experiment I used techniques that are standard to experimental economics. Basically I have participants performing an interactive task with an opponent for 30 rounds. They are paid conditional on their performance, not a fixed fee. Each round participants are randomly re-matched, i.e., they are assigned to a different opponents. Everything is anonymous, so no reputation effect. Moreover, rounds are incentivised such that they are viewd as independent from each other (one random round is selected for payment at the end of the experiment).
Participants know that from the very beginning.

Comment: Please add this important details to the post itself as an edit, and not only as a comment. Comments are easily overlooked!